# The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value:... cannot convert int64 to string and Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal string

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, yaml, kubectl, amazon-eks

I'm sure regarding YAML format and kubernetes (AWS EKS) as per validations of [Kubeval](https://kubeval.instrumenta.dev/) & [Yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/).

The following is a aws-auth-patch.yml file.

[image]

However... When I executed in CMD **kubectl patch configmap/aws-auth -n kube-system --patch "$(cat aws-auth-patch.yml)"**

*error: Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}*

Also in Windows PowerShell **kubectl patch configmap/aws-auth -n kube-system --patch $(Get-Content aws-auth-patch.yml -Raw)**

*error: The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "map[apiVersion:v1 data:map[....etc...": cannot convert int64 to string*

I think that YAML file format is normal.

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by change my OS from Windows 10 to WSL (Windows Sub-system for Linux ) (ubuntu 20.04 LTS) and now the below command executed successfully.

```
kubectl patch configmap/aws-auth -n kube-system --patch "$(cat aws-auth-patch.yml)"
```

and result is:

```
configmap/aws-auth patched
```